# How to create a vector of strings from multi dimensional arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

The original problem is that I am reading big chunks of binary data from a tool that is being developed.

My goal is to read data and parse it to a human readable text such as a .csv file, so I have to flatten 
that data.

The data is in form of samples of a multidimensional array of floats, longs or ints or whatever. And 
because the tool is under development the size and dimensions of the array may differ from an hour to hour!

(e.g. right now I may have samples of a 2*2 matrix, two hours from now they may change the data struct to 
1*4, or an array of 16*12*128,...)

One part of the problem is to generate the header line of the .CSV file. I need a method that can 
generate an array of strings like this:

for a 2*2: data_0_0, data_0_1, data_1_0, data_1_1, and

for a 1*4: data_0, data_1, data_2, data_3,

for a 3*4*2: data_0_0_0, data_0_0_1, data_0_0_2,...., data_2_3_0, data_2_3_1,

and so on ...

The only information that I can get from the tool each time is the dimensions and size of the array.
The tool may tell me {1}, which  means a single value, {12} means an array with a length of 12, {3,4,5} 
means a " 3x4x5 " element array and so on and so forth... Therefore, I need to be able to flatten any array 
of a*b*c*..*x. (which should not be too hard as I can have a single for loop.

So, I'd like to create a method that generates a vector of strings (in above format) from ANY multidimensional array.

Therefore I think at the end, the header generating method will  lookalike something this

```
public string[] GenerateNames(string dataBlockName, int[] dimensions)
{




}
```

One simple solution is to have lets say 10 For-loops and hope that the raw data will never have an array that has more than 10 dimensions. However, I'm looking for a better, cleaner, nicer solution!
There are a lot of questions asking how to change a vector into multidimensional  arrays. My goal is the exact opposite thing and a header line with unlimited flexibility!

Thanks a lot in advance fellas!

-- 
Someone below suggested to use "Depth First Traversal" which I am going to look into now. Initial googling seemed promising.

Comment: Is the array rectangular or jagged?  i.e. is it `foo[][]` or `foo[,]`?

Comment: for a fact I know they are rectangular.

Comment: Do a depth-first traversal of your array.

Comment: I wrote a piece of code my self that solves the issue. I can post it as an answer later.

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten any array by merely iterating it in a `foreach` loop, adding each item to a list, and then converting that list back to an array.

```
public T[] Flatten<T>(Array array)    
{
    var list = new List<T>();

    foreach (T item in array)
    {
        list.Add(item);
    }

    return list.ToArray();
}
```

where `array` is a rectangular array of any shape.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the array with the size, as you can check the dimensions by using the Rank property of the Array class, and the corresponding methods for obtaining the values. With this in mind and the good old .net 1.0 Array class you can write a method like this one:

```
public T[] Flatten<T>(Array source)
{
    var arrayIndex = new int[source.Rank];
    var result = new T[Enumerable.Range(0, source.Rank).Sum(i => source.GetUpperBound(i))];
    var index = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < source.Rank; i++)
    {
        for(var j = 0; j < source.GetUpperBound(i); j++) 
        {
            arrayIndex[i] = j;
            result[index++] = (T)source.GetValue(arrayIndex);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

It's more convoluted than a foreach, but it will provide greater flexibility on how you could traverse the original array (which is dependent on the .net implementation). As Array is not a generic class you will need to provide the element type on the method, so that for an array of integers you can call it as:

```
Flatten<int>(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Buffer.BlockCopy` is handy here.

Note: there are some special cases to deal with so take this as pseudocode.

```
public T[] Flatten<T>(Array source) 
{
   int byteCount = Buffer.ByteLength(source);  
   int sizeofT = Buffer.ByteLength(new T[1]);

    T[] dest = new T[(byteCount + sizeofT - 1) / sizeofT];  
    Buffer.BlockCopy(source,0,dest,0,byteCount);

    return dest;   
}
```

Comment: What are the special cases?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Some special cases that aren't handled are: `source` being null or empty. `source` not being an array of `T` could cause various size mismatches or mappings that require interpretation.